# Two abstracts needed in apa6

Tags: languages, abstract, apa6

I am supposed to write a manuscript based on `apa6`. Unfortunately I am located in Germany, so my professor wants to have 2 (!) abstracts - one in English ("Abstract" - as implemented in `apa6` already) and an additional one, called "Zusammenfassung" (literal translation into German).

Does anybody have an idea how to get this done? I really don't want to manually insert a page...

Answer (score 6):

The class has no provision for multiple abstracts. However you can still put another abstract, stretching a bit the `\abstract` command.

Add the option `ngerman` for `babel`,

```
\usepackage[ngerman,american]{babel}
```

and then type the abstract as

```
\abstract{This is the abstract in English.
  \begin{otherlanguage}{ngerman}
% \par\medskip
% \section{\normalfont\normalsize\abstractname}
  \noindent Die Zusammenfassung.\par
  \end{otherlanguage}}
```

Depending on the style chosen, the word “Abstract” appears or not. Without a minimal example of your setup it's difficult to chose between the possibility.

If “Abstract” appears in the document, then uncomment the second line, otherwise uncomment the `\par\medskip` line.

---

For keywords you can follow a similar path.

1. Add

   ```
   \addto\captionsngerman{%
     \providecommand{\keywordsname}{}%
     \renewcommand{\keywordsname}{Schl\"usselw\"orter}}
   ```

   to your document preamble, after `\usepackage[ngerman,american]{babel}`
2. Specify your keywords as

   ```
   \keywords{Keyword one, keyword two
     \par\medskip
     \indent
     \begin{otherlanguage}{ngerman}
     \textit{\keywordsname:} Schl\"usselwort eins, Schl\"usselwort zwei
     \end{otherlanguage}
   }
   ```

[image]

Comment: thx a lot again for your helpful advice.
unfortunately i think i didnt explain my problem exactly enough.
i need: first page: abstract + keywords; 2nd page: Zusammenfassung + Schlüsselwörter.
i can achieve a two page abstract with your method by inserting a \clearpage command. but by doing this keywords (or Schlüsselwörter) will only appear on the second page.

Comment: @henning Can you please add to your question the document preamble? The `apa6` class has lots of options.

Answer (score 0):

I did it otherwise. I used the [abstract package](http://www.weinelt.de/latex/abstract.html)

So kinda like that:

```
\documentclass[doc]{apa6}
    \usepackage[ngerman,american]{babel} 
    \usepackage{abstract}
    \include{Titelei}%Title, Author etc.
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \newpage
       \include{abstract}%you also could place the abstracts here but I placed them in another file
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And in the abstract.tex file I placed the following:

```
\selectlanguage{american}
  \begin{abstract}
       \noident
       \blindtext\\
       \textbf{Keywords:} Keyword1
  \end{abstract}

\clearpage     

\selectlanguage{ngerman}
  \begin{abstract}
      \noident
      \blindtext\\
      \textbf{Schlüsselbegriffe:} Schlüsselbegriff 1 2 und 3
  \end{abstract}
```

Keep in mind: You will loose the \keywords{} command. Maybee someone knows why or how to fix this, but I guess this patchwork could help for bachelor-thesis for example.

Please excuse bad formating (my first post here).

I'd love to get suggestions on the \keywords problem :)