# two abstract in article

Tags: abstract, apa6

I need to include two abstracts (english and spanish) with their respective keywords, I am using the package `apa6` but these only put the latest `\abstract{}` text.  How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}
\abstract{El tema de la evaluación educativa ...}
\keywords{evaluación, aprendizaje, decreto 1290 de 2009.}
\abstract{ The issue of educational evaluation is one }
\keywords{assessment, learning, decree 1290 of 2009.}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This has already been asked: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119292/two-abstracts-needed-in-apa6 If this doesn't help, please say so; if it helps, this question can be closed. Don't worry, in this case, and continue to contribute to the site.