# APA6 - class - 2 abstracts

Tags: abstract, apa6

I am working with the documentclass APA-6. I am required to write down two abstracts, one in english, one in german ("Zusammenfassung"). Thus, I need an abstract page and a "Zusammenfassung" page in abstract style plus keywords/ "Schlüsselwörter".

This is not working so far. When I add another \abstract, I receive an error (plus, I don't know how to force LaTeX to call it "Zusammenfassung". I also don't know how to replace keywords with "Schlüsselwörter" in the german "Zusammenfassung".

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man]{apa6}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Umlaute und Sonderzeichen

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %nutzt Babel mit neuer Rechtschreibung
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex} %Definition der Parameter von Biblatex: biber + apa
\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}%mod.
\usepackage[locale=US]{siunitx}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}

\title{Test title}
\shorttitle{Short one}

\author{Me}
\affiliation{here}
\leftheader{Me}

\abstract{Here goes some text.}
\keywords{Some interesting stuff 1, and 2}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Text comes here.

\end{document}
```

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119292/two-abstracts-needed-in-apa6

This did not help (see comments).

Comment: As I said in my answer to the linked question, the `apa6` class has no provision for two abstracts, so *extensive* work is needed to accomplish your need.

Comment: What a pity. Seems to be requested by many people. Would it make sense to give some reward for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work ***only*** with the `man` option. For the `jou` option a similar patch could be defined. But it's pretty sure that a journal requesting this class for a submission will reject the paper.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man]{apa6}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[locale=US]{siunitx}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\maketitle}
  {\@ifundefined{@abstract}{}}
  {\jens@process@abstracts\@gobble}
  {}{}

\let\jens@process@abstracts\@empty

\renewcommand{\abstract}[2][english]{%
  \@namedef{jens@abstract@#1}{#2}%
  \g@addto@macro\jens@process@abstracts{\jens@do@abstract{#1}}%
  \let\@abstract\@empty
}
\renewcommand{\keywords}[2][english]{%
  \@namedef{jens@keywords@#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand\jens@do@abstract[1]{%
  \begin{otherlanguage}{#1}
  \section{\normalfont\normalsize\abstractname}%
  \@nameuse{jens@abstract@#1}\par
  \@ifundefined{jens@keywords@#1}{}{%
    \setlength{\parindent}{0.4in}% BDB
    \indent\textit{\keywordname:} \@nameuse{jens@keywords@#1}%
  }%
  \end{otherlanguage}
  \newpage
}
\makeatother

\addto\captionsenglish{%
  \renewcommand{\keywordname}{Keywords}%
}
\addto\captionsngerman{%
  \renewcommand{\keywordname}{Schl\"usselw\"orte}%
}



\begin{document}
\title{Test title}
\shorttitle{Short one}

\author{Me}
\affiliation{here}
\leftheader{Me}

\abstract{Here goes some text.}
\keywords{Some interesting stuff 1, and 2}

\abstract[ngerman]{This should be in German}
\keywords[ngerman]{Also this}

\maketitle

Text comes here.

\end{document}
```

The abstracts are typeset in the order they're specified.

[image]

### A version also for the `jou` option

Note that this applies with both the `man` and `jou` option, since the definition of `\jens@do@abstract` changes based on the given option.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,jou]{apa6}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[locale=US]{siunitx}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\maketitle}
  {\@ifundefined{@abstract}}
  {\par\jens@process@abstracts\@gobbletwo}
  {}{}

\let\jens@process@abstracts\@empty

\renewcommand{\abstract}[2][english]{%
  \@namedef{jens@abstract@#1}{#2}%
  \g@addto@macro\jens@process@abstracts{\jens@do@abstract{#1}}%
  \let\@abstract\@empty
}
\renewcommand{\keywords}[2][english]{%
  \@namedef{jens@keywords@#1}{#2}%
}

\@ifundefined{def@jou}{% man option
  \newcommand\jens@do@abstract[1]{%
    \begin{otherlanguage}{#1}%
    \section{\normalfont\normalsize\abstractname}%
    \@nameuse{jens@abstract@#1}\par
    \@ifundefined{jens@keywords@#1}{}{%
      \setlength{\parindent}{0.4in}% BDB
      \indent\textit{\keywordname:} \@nameuse{jens@keywords@#1}%
    }%
    \end{otherlanguage}
    \newpage
  }
}{% jou option
  \newcommand\jens@do@abstract[1]{%
    \par\parbox{4.6875in}{%
      \begin{otherlanguage}{#1}%
      \small\noindent\@nameuse{jens@abstract@#1}%
      \@ifundefined{jens@keywords@#1}{}{%
        \par\vspace{0.12in}\raggedright\textit{\keywordname:} %
        \@nameuse{jens@keywords@#1}%
      }%
      \end{otherlanguage}%
    }%
    \vspace{0.24in}%
  }
}
\makeatother

\addto\captionsenglish{%
  \renewcommand{\keywordname}{Keywords}%
}
\addto\captionsngerman{%
  \renewcommand{\keywordname}{Schl\"usselw\"orte}%
}



\begin{document}
\title{Test title}
\shorttitle{Short one}

\author{Me}
\affiliation{here}
\leftheader{Me}

\abstract{\lipsum*[2]}
\keywords{Some interesting stuff 1, and 2}

\abstract[ngerman]{\lipsum*[3]}
\keywords[ngerman]{Also this}

\maketitle

Text comes here. \lipsum

\end{document}
```