# Does the APA6-Class "Keywords" do anything but formatting?

Tags: abstract, apa6, keywords

everyone,

I was wondering if the "Keyword" command from the APA6 class does anything more than just formatting.
(e.g. pass as PDF keywords or similar?)

> It does not

: **does anyone know how these are formatted**?

Thank you in advance for your efforts and answers.

PS: concerning [2 Abstracts in apa6 Document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119292/two-abstracts-needed-in-apa6/495788#495788)

Comment: No, it simply copies the list of keywords into the abstract.

Comment: I thought so to. But if it is only formatting the Task of multiple Abstracts in an apa6 Document should be easy to be dealt with. Or am i wrong now?